# What does an identifier do in C function parameter list? For example: int foo(int IDENTIFIER parameter_name);

Tags: c

Does anyone know what an identifier does in a C function parameter list?
The code looks like

```
#define IDENTIFIER_NAME
int foo(int IDENTIFIER_NAME x);
```

I appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `#define` does not provide a replacement for `IDENTIFIER_NAME`, C preprocessor removes the string from the source code.

This trick may be used for writing custom tools that process C files to collect identifier names: one could write a very simple script that finds `IDENTIFIER_NAME` in the source, grab the next token, and add it to the list of identifiers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In what situation would you write custom tools to collect identifier names? If you don't mind me asking.

Comment: @user3416828 Usually this is done to automate some routine task that needs access to things that are available in source code, but unavailable in compiled code, such as names of function parameters. Solutions like that are usually less robust than the "honest" ones based on established C/C++ parsers, because they trade ease of coding the tool for the additional effort on part of coders of the actual code. This is always a bad tradeoff, because coders of the actual code tend to forget the marker, and their code continues to work properly.